# How to customize user profile in SharePoint 2013 by Organizational position?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, community-site

Is it possible for a user profile be different by Organizational position in color or what can be viewed etc?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "not out of the box". You can display different properties if you use User Profile Sub Types. But there is no automation to apply a UPST to a profile, you would have to manage that yourself. Once done, the profile display is handled for you.

As for different colors, you can but, again, noting out of the box to handle this. You would have to modify the OOB Profile page to detect the property change and apply alternate CSS to change the page styling. I did this quite a while ago for a company that allowed the employees to align themselves with different Games. Then we would change their profile with CSS to match the game they chose.